# Azure Django initial response time

Tags: python, django, azure, load, azure-web-app-service

I publish my django website in Azure.

But I have long load time, first loading can be 16-18 sec, after 2-7 sec

[image]

What I need to check?

If I need change settings? For example debug="true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a slow start up time only on the first request, you can try enabling always on. To enable always on: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/.

For further speed up tips, please see this blog entry: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/10-ways-to-speed-up-your-wordpress-site-on-azure-websites/. Although it is targeted to Wordpress some of the same tips are applicable to Python.

In general, you should not have `debug=true` for production apps since it's a big security hole.